# NetBeans SSL and command line arguments: Server doesn't receive the message

Tags: java, netbeans, ssl, command-line-arguments, netbeans-7.1

I'm not sure how to put it, but here is my problem.
I want to test SSL from here http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php. I am using NetBeans 7.1. In each void main, if I insert this piece of code `for (int i=0; i<arstring.length; i++) 
                System.out.println(arstring[i]);`, I see the arguments are passed correctly.

However, when i run Server and Client (each in a separate folder and each with the cerificate file), the moment I type something into client, the execution of both classes stops and the message from Client is NOT received by the server.

I am really stuck here.
This is my first time working with Java for communication via Internet, so please try to explain in a simple way why is my program not working.

Comment: Do you get any meaningful messages when appending `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` to your command line arguments?